# How i can put a picture above a border in css?

Tags: css, image, border

I want to know how I can manage something like this in css.

[image]

I mean the **M**, in my case this is a picture of a letter, which have to go over a border.

I try it on tipeeestream on a event list, and I've tried some things, but doesn't work. The problem is, that I don't get a good resource about their css style and I have to get a informations about the browser about their css sytle.

Can someone help me out please?

Edit: This is my css code in their editor

```css
 .event .left {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 0 3px 3px;
    border-color: black; 
 }
.left {
    
    position:relative;
    width: 50px;
    
}
.left:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
.event .middle, .event .right {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    border-color: black;
}
.event.middle-event .middle, .event.middle-event .left, .event.middle-event .right{
    background: transparent;
    border-style: none;
}
.event.last-event .middle, .event.last-event .left, .event.last-event .right{
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: can you share the HTML/CSS you tried, *(I hardly understand what you say you tried but my english is not my language)*

Comment: Are you able to try and recreate what you have done so far in a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can try and fix your code?

Comment: Try `position: absolute`

Comment: .yourimg {float:left; margin-top: -20px}

Comment: i will try my best, but i dont have the full css code, because tipeeestream give only an css editor to edit somethings, i will put this into my main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with absolute and relative positioning for each of the elements, the background, the M, and the "eanwhile".

http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/zBoGXY

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="m">M</div>
<div id="title">eanwhile</div>
</div>

#background {width:500px; height:100px; background-color: yellow; border:4px solid black; position:relative;}

#m {font-size:220px; position:absolute; top:-80px;}

#title {font-size:70px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:180px;}
```

Comment: guys, u are awesome! so many people who helps me, i really appreciated it! i think i have to check how tipeeestream include the picture or i have to change it

Answer (score 0):

You can set overflow: visible to the element containing the image and then give the image negative margin top.

eg:

```
<div style="overflow: visible;">
    <img src="..." style="margin-top: -40px" />
    ...
</div>
```

I have styled them using inline styles only for demo purposes, the styles should be applied using classes if you want to follow best practice.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters mentioned, please include the code that you have tried so far next time.

Using CSS, the easiest way to do this is set the element with the border (I've chosen the class `.box`) to have `position:relative;`. Then put the image in the box, and set its position as: `position:absolute;`. After this, you can move the image around freely, relative to the `.box`. Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/dimonilife/edit?html,css,output

Comment: okay, i understand this, thanks i will try it. i try it with the overflow, but the image will not goes over the border.